# My js scripts are not including in my file when I try to include it in head section

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a header.php file in which I'm adding my scripts file but can't add properly these files works fine in my footer.php file but not working in header.php file.

I need to add them in header so I can run the code in my files too.

I am adding my js scripts jquery with other scripts in my file but it is not working on my page on my console there is no any error but when I check in network i see this message:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/mvc/public/js/jquery-2.0.2.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

this code works fine when I put it in footer section. But it should work in head section too. 
here is my code im adding this in head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>public/js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>public/js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>public/js/creditcard.js"></script>
```

I believe its a strange behavior. But how can I fix it?

Please let me know in comments if this question is not good and not explaining well.
Thanks.

Comment: And how/where do you set variable `URL`?

Comment: it is defined with define('URL', 'http://localhost/MVC/');

Comment: Are you sure it is defined before head.php is processed?

Comment: the message just means that browser has cached your file already

Comment: BTW not sure what is `URL`, i was thinking PHP variable need `$` in front, sorry, i'm not a PHP guy

Comment: @A.Wolff URL seems to be constant, so it doesn't need $ sign

Comment: @EdgarZakaryan of course, i was just thinking about that ;)

Comment: URL is just working fine and its just a defined. the problem is it does not work in header but it works in footer file.

Comment: `MVC` is not the same as `mvc`, not on LINUX anyway. Could be that.

Comment: So please define 'Not working'?!

Comment: I changed that too @Fred-ii-

Comment: @A.Wolff jquery is not getting in my file so I can't work with any jquery code as I need to write some jquery in my main files which comes with header automatically.

Comment: well that weird. Try using hardcoded url in your script <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mvc/public/js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

Comment: @m3dev I tried that too.. -_- in vain.

Comment: instead the stylesheet is working fine with the same url/method <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/default.css" />

Comment: Need your help guys :'(

Comment: Just an idea -- is your URL **literally** `localhost/mvc/public...`, or is it `http://localhost/...`? If no "http/https", it might be trying to fetch it relative to the current path. Just an idea. There's obviously something odd going on.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the suggestion. I tried that too but unfortunately the link for stylesheet is working great but the problem is only with script.

Answer (score 0):

304 does not really indicate an error, but rather indicates that the resource for the requested URL has not changed since last accessed or cached.

Try just typing out the hardcoded URL `/mvc/public/js/jquery-2.0.2.js` as the source URL.